# Will this break anything? alias l='ls -ltra'

Tags: bash, alias, ls, .profile

Will this break anything?

```
alias l='ls -ltra'
```

I usually set this alias in .profile in AIX.

Answer (score 2):

The default `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu (`/etc/skel/.bashrc`) uses

```
alias l='ls -CF'
```

But as far as I know no program or script relies on this (and it would be quite bad to do so), so I don't expect your version to break anything. Just be careful if you are following some tutorial or other doc that uses `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Florian Diesch has properly pointed out that default `~/.bashrc` already contains an alias `l`:

```
$ grep 'alias l=' ~/.bashrc
alias l='ls -CF'
```

where, `-C` is to list entries by column and `-F` is to classify entries by into directories,executable files, etc.

It won't break anything, since aliases are typically for shells only, therefore no external command uses them. Other *nix-like operating systems typically have utilities with same name but their option flags may differ. I've compared `-ltra` flags for `ls` in  [AIX man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ls.htm#ls__row-d3e72998) as well as `man ls` on my Ubuntu 16.04, and options correspond to each other. So you can expect the same behavior on Ubuntu as on AIX for that alias.

As Florian also pointed out, you need to remember that your `l` alias is custom and not be confused by differences in output of standard `l` alias and your custom one.